# BusReservation email markup not working through scripts.google.com

Tags: email, gmail, json-ld, google-schemas

I created a JSON-LD script for a bus reservation ticket including only the mandatory fields and sent mail through scripts.google.com, but the mail is not getting added to Gmail calendar.

```json
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "BusReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "XYZ",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
  "reservationFor" : {
    "@type" : "BusTrip",
    "busCompany" : {
      "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "ABCD"
    },
    "departureBusStop" : {
      "@type" : "BusStop",
      "name" : "ANAND VIHAR",
      "address" : {
        "@type" : "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress" : "Isbt Anand Vihar, Anand Vihar, New Delhi, Delhi 110092",
        "addressLocality" : "Anand Vihar Bus station"
      }
    },
    "departureTime" : "2017-06-21T21:30",
    "arrivalBusStop" : {
      "@type" : "BusStop",
      "name" : "Delhi"
    },
    "arrivalTime" : "2017-06-22T21:30"
  },
  "underName" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "Mr Aditya Banerjee"
  },
  "price" : "562",
  "reservedTicket" : {
    "@type" : "Ticket",
    "ticketedSeat" : {
      "@type" : "Seat",
      "seatNumber" : "15"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: test with https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: @AlfinPaul: Thanks for the quick reply. I tested on the above site and found this issue:  reservationNumber 
XYZ (The property reservationNumber is not recognized by Google for an object of type BusReservation.)  price 
562 (The property price is not recognized by Google for an object of type BusReservation.)  busCompany 
The property busCompany is not recognized by Google for an object of type BusTrip.  But according to [Link](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/bus-reservation), these fields are correct

Comment: @AdityaBanerjee I don't think the BusReservation schema integrates with Calendar. The documentation only mentions integration with Now cards (https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/bus-reservation).

Comment: @Franco Thanks for the info. That really helped